# Angular2 - Reactive Form Properties

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form that I am generating for my component. There are about 5 optional select inputs that a user could choose to use and pick criteria from.

I am trying to implement some error messages in this but can't quite figure something out.

`<span *ngIf="importForm.invalid && importForm.touched" class="help-block text-danger">Please select one piece of data to filter by.</span>`

Since all of the fields are options, but at least one is required, how could I go about checking that one of the fields has been `touched` prior to showing the invalid message?

**Component:**

```
/**
 * Render the form in the UI to allow
 *
 * @memberof FilterSearchComponent
 */
renderForm() {
    this.importForm = this.fb.group({
        costCenter: [[]],
        area: [[]],
        silo: [[]],
        department: [[]],
        location: [[]],
        segment: [[]],
        role: [[]]
    },
        {
            validator: (formGroup: FormGroup) => {
                return this.validateFilter(formGroup);
            }
        });
}

/**
 * Checks to see that at least one of the filter
 * options have been filled out prior to searching
 * for employees.
 *
 * @param formGroup
 */
validateFilter(formgroup: FormGroup) {
    if (formgroup.controls["costCenter"].value.length ||
        formgroup.controls["area"].value.length ||
        formgroup.controls["silo"].value.length ||
        formgroup.controls["department"].value.length ||
        formgroup.controls["location"].value.length ||
        formgroup.controls["segment"].value.length ||
        formgroup.controls["role"].value.length
    ) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return { noFilterOptions: true };
    }
}
```

I really don't want to have to do an `||` statement for each of the controls in my HTML if I can help it.

Are there any other ways I can see if ANY input in my form has been touched instead of specifying the one I want to look at on an individual basis ?

Comment: I don't have anything handy to verify this and post as an answer, but `FormGroup` and `FormControl` (and probably `FormArray`) inherit from `AbstractControl` which has a `touched()` method. You should be able to call this method on the `FormGroup` and find out if it or any of the child `FormControls` have been touched... You can also use the `value` property of the `FormControl` and iterate over the values w/out having to know the form control names...

Comment: How did it go with the answers, did either match your requirement? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I would want to remove the custom validator as it sits now. It will be fired whenever something happens to your form, which I assume has more values than just the selects. This would fire unnecessary often.

Instead I would listen to `click` event, or something similar of your choosing. The following example could probably be refined some more (?), but at least you have something to work with if you'd choose to do it the following way.

Here I assume that instead of using an array for all `select` in the form, you'd just want to capture one value, for which a single `FormControl` would do:

```ts
this.importForm = this.fb.group({
  optionals: this.fb.group({
    costCenter: [''],
    area: ['']        
  })
});
```

After build of form, I like to store the different controls to variables, to avoid lengthy code with property paths. I would iterate the object properties in the formgroup `optionals`, store it in array, which we can then check that at least one value is set:

```ts
this.optionalCtrl = this.importForm.controls.optionals
```

In template, well, here you would need to set the click event for all selects separately...

```html
<select formControlName="costCenter" (click)="checkOptionals()">
```

In `checkOptionals` would then iterate the object properties in the formgroup `optionals` and check that at least one property has a value other than an empty string. Based on this we set a custom error to the formgroup, or alternatively clear it.

```ts
checkOptionals() {
  for(let key in this.optionalCtrl.controls ) {
    if(this.optionalCtrl.controls[key].value != '') {
      this.optionalCtrl.clearValidators()
      // this.optionalCtrl.updateValueAndValidity()
      break;
    } else {
      this.optionalCtrl.setErrors({"noFilterOptions": true})
    }
  }
```

}
    }

You might need to call `updateValueAndValidity` after setting the error. Then in template you just show this error when it's truthy:

```html
<div *ngIf="optionalCtrl.hasError('noFilterOptions')">
  choose at least one to filter by
</div>
```

DEMO: http://plnkr.co/edit/VbtsYST0KAUqe8BRQlmt?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

What you have here should work:

```
<span *ngIf="importForm.invalid && importForm.touched" class="help-block text-danger">Please select one piece of data to filter by.</span>
```

The form's touched property should be set if any of the controls on the form have been touched. I assume it is not working? How is it not working?

Touched -> the user entered and left the input element. It says nothing about whether the user entered something into the input element.

If you want to know if the user updated the value of one of the input elements, use dirty instead:

```
<span *ngIf="importForm.invalid && importForm.dirty" 
      class="help-block text-danger">
   Please select one piece of data to filter by.
</span>
```

Comment: What if a select input is opened and closed without selecting a value, is that considered `touched` ?

Comment: I would assume so as long as the user *leaves* the field afterward. But you may want to run a small test to confirm.

Comment: Strange, expanding and then closing the dropdown doesnt trigger this as touched. If I select a value and then remove the value, it works just fine.

Comment: Even if you then leave the field? Interesting. Not what I would have guessed. It seems that clicking on the drop down icon is not considered to be "entering" the field?